# How to intercept dialling numbers (like ussd)

Tags: java, android

I'd like to make my app to take some action when certain number (code) is dialled in the phone, just like when we type *#06# to show the IMEI (USSD codes). I've been researching for more than 2 hours for a solution but can't find. Maybe I am using the wrong keywords (english is not my native language), or maybe it is impossible to do. Please, can anybody help me? I am not asking for a complete solution, if you can tell me only if it is possible and point the directions would help me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: [It looks like there's a broadcast that gets sent when a special code is entered](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/nougat-release/src/com/android/dialer/SpecialCharSequenceMgr.java#176), you can try playing around with that. Here's another helpful resource: http://simonmarquis.github.io/Android-SecretCodes/

Comment: @AndrewSun, thank you! I will have a look.

Comment: Just a heads up-  I worked at a place a few years ago that patented this functionality (launching an application when a number is dialed).  The patent is now owned by Nuance Communications.  You may not legally be able to do this even if you figure out how without paying them.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I do not want to "lauch an application when a number is dialed". My application is already lauched...

Answer (score -1):

```
String ussd = "*" + Uri.encode ("#")+"06"+Uri.encode ("#");
startActivity (new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse ("tel:" + ussd)));
```

Also you have to use `android.permission.CALL_PHONE`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will analise your code and try to use it in my app!